# Store list elements in single variable for query

Tags: python

I am currently facing a probably very simple problem and think too complicated to solve.

I got a excel-file with city names and postal codes.

I read the file and export the postal codes (PLZ) with

```
zipfile = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")
zipcode = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['PLZ']).values
```

Output is: [80331][80333] ....

Each ZIP code is later used to conduct a query on a website.

For that I use bs4 and request and the follwing line of code (is not the complete code, just the relevant line):

```
data = {'tx_ybpn_storefinder[searchReq][term]': zip}
```

The process is:

1. Enter the ZIP code from the list (in "zip")
2. Query on the website
3. Save the results (data) of the website-query
4. Query with the next ZIP code
5. Save data from query
6. Repeat for every zip code in the list

I think I have to work here with a for/while-loop-combination, but actually I dont know how. Is it necessary to store each zip code in a unique variable?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Merge all the zip codes in one list and then use `for i in list` to loop through zip codes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I think I have to work here with a for/while-loop-combination

Right. Loop over the values in the `PLZ` column:

```
zipcode = pd.read_excel("file.xlsx")

for zip in zipcode['PLZ']:
    data = {'tx_ybpn_storefinder[searchReq][term]': zip}
    # query the website, etc.
```